# How to accelerate substitution when using GNU sed with GNU find?

Tags: linux, sed, find, gnu, xargs

I have the results of a numerical simulation that consist of hundreds of directories; each directory contains millions of text files.

I need to substitute a the string "`wavelength;`"  with "`wavelength_bc;`" so I have tried both the following:

```
find . -type f -exec sed -i 's/wavelength;/wavelength_bc;/g' {} \;
```

and

```
find . -type f -exec sed -i 's/wavelength;/wavelength_bc;/g' {} +
```

Unfortunately, the commands above take a very long time to finish, (more than 1 hour).

I wonder how can I take advantage of the number of cores on my machine (8) to accelerate the command above?

I am thinking of using `xargs` with `-P` flag. I'm scared that that will corrupt the files; so I have no idea if that is safe or not?

In summary:

- How can I accelerate `sed` substitutions when using with `find`?
- Is it safe to uses `xargs -P` to run that in parallel?

Thank you

Comment: Yes `xargs -P` should be perfectly safe to use

Comment: @anubhava: Thanks! I am trying it now. Could you please write an answer?

Comment: It should be safe (but less efficient) even if it happened that some of the files were listed more than once in the input to `xargs -P sed -i [...]`, though there will be no such duplication when the input is coming from `find`'s output.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`xargs -P` should be safe to use, however you will need to use `-print0` option of `find` and piping to `xargs -0` to address filenames with spaces or wildcards:

```sh
find . -type f -print0 |
xargs -0 -I {} -P 0 sed -i 's/wavelength;/wavelength_bc;/g' {}
```

`-P 0` option in `xargs` will run in Parallel mode. It will run as many processes as possible for your CPU.

Comment: `-P 8` will always run 8 jobs in parallel but `-P 0` will check your processor and will run as many parallel jobs as possible for that CPU. Note that since you have 8 core processor so `-P 0` is effectively same as `-P 8`.

Comment: using that command, it finished after : `real 43m15.117s
user 39m54.227s
sys 53m27.121s`

Comment: ok so that's some improvement

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you (GNU sed & parallel):

```
find . -type f | parallel -q sed -i 's/wavelength;/wavelength_bc;/g' {}
```

GNU parallel will run as many jobs as there are cores on the machine in parallel.

More sophisticated uses can involve remote servers and file transfer see [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/) and a cheatsheet [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/parallel_cheat.pdf).

Comment: You must escape the semicolons in order for this to work!

Comment: @s.ouchene Oops! alternatives are use parallel `-q` option or enclose single quotes like so `'...'` becomes `\''...'\'`.